# Concise phrase for "former employees' tasks"

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language, synonyms

I'm looking for a short, snappy alternative word/phrase meaning "person who has left the company".

I have very limited space available (20 characters) for a label that conveys (in prose):

> List of tasks that are open but assigned to somebody who has left the company

I've tried Thesaurus.com but can't find anything graceful with this precise meaning. "Ex-staff" for example, is adequately short, but equally unpleasant.

Given our wonderful language's habit of a word for every occasion I'm surprised I'm finding nothing suitable!

Comment: *Former employee* has 15 characters.

Comment: I have 20 characters to express the whole thing:
List of tasks that are open but assigned to somebody who has left the company

Comment: You may need to update the question title.

Comment: Why? The 20 character parameter is only mentioned in the body of the question. But if you'd like to edit please go for it!

Comment: There we are. In fact that's only 22 characters.

Comment: Cheers! Still overshooting by 2 but certainly an improvement!

Comment: Left Behind Tasks. Connotes what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd call those **orphaned tasks**; they're still alive, but their parent is gone.

Comment: I like this! Elegant. However, my users tend to struggle unless terms are sufficiently blunt in their purpose. Having said that, I may still go with this, it's good.

Answer (score 1):

If they are simply tasks that need to be done, why does it matter that they were left by former employees? Try: Unfinished or undelegated tasks

Comment: Unfortunately, they aren't simply tasks that need to be done. They are specifically those assigned to people who have left.

Answer (score 0):

Ex-colleague or past/former colleague? Ex-workmate or past/former workmate?  'Former shipmate' if chumminess is permitted.  'Departee, but that implies ongoing process, and 'departed' is definitely not appropriate!

'Escapee' or 'gone AWOL' if your situation allows such levity; 'deserter' if you're feeling bitter.

Comment: It's a business document so levity is best avoided, and our 'deserters' may not all have 'deserted' voluntarily!

Comment: The other suggestions are OK but are still a bit too long for my tastes!

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my hat in:

**Masterless tasks**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I need the precision of 'former employee'. Masterless would also apply to those tasks that have never been assigned. For what I'm doing this is a subtle but important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is bluntness: **abandoned tasks**.